# Сделал счастливым - какое сказуемое?

Tags: синтаксис, сказуемые

> Она сделала меня счастливым.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какое здесь сказуемое и чем оно выражено?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, что это задача решается так.

1. ***Я стал (сделался) счастливым.*** Это составное именное сказуемое. Связка «стал» согласуется с подлежащим и с  именной частью сказуемого, **двунаправленная** связь.
2. ***Она сделала меня счастливым.*** Это уже не составное именное сказуемое, так как нет согласования именной части с подлежащим «она», но есть согласование **с дополнением «меня».**

Это тоже двунаправленная связь, но уже с **дополнением**: сделала (кого?) меня, сделала (каким?) счастливым.

Тогда получается, что «счастливым» – это определение, отнесенное к дополнению,  но согласуется оно с дополнением только в числе и роде, а падеж ему задает глагол.

4. В книге Кустовой 2013 года (в теме «члены предложения с двунаправленными связями») есть такой пример с дополнением: Пусть он помнит (кого?) меня  (какой?) **молодой.**

Также она говорит о том, что члены с двунаправленными связями могут выражаться прилагательными,  причастиями, например: *Тебя сюда привезли **шестилетним**. Я застала ее **плачущей**.*

Comment: Спасибо вам большое! То есть мы можем задавать вопрос к дополнению "каким"? Или лучше "кем"?

Comment: Игорь, спасибо за вопрос, извините, я исправляю ответ. Посмотрела еще раз тему у Кустовой.   Дополнением является  только «меня», а прилагательное с двунаправленной связью "счастливым" относится к дополнению.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!Теперь все прояснилось!) Не хватает благодарностей за ваши труд и любовь к языку!

Comment: @Sharon Думаю, что в Вашем ответе надо подправить: _**она сделала** меня счастливым_.

Comment: @Римма Михайлова  Спасибо, Римма!  Вот нет у меня редактора,  а писать приходится много (надо как-то оправдаться). Вы уж по возможности исправляйте такие ошибки, пожалуйста. И вы нас совсем забыли, вас здесь не хватает …

Comment: @Игорь Болотов  Спасибо, Игорь! Я же желаю вам успешно следовать заветам нашего гения во всех науках:  «О вы, которых ожидает Отечество от недр своих И видеть таковых желает…Дерзайте ныне ободренны Раченьем вашим показать, Что может собственных Платонов И быстрых разумом Невтонов Российская земля рождать».

Comment: И вот что еще по теме. Кустова вообще не говорит о  синтаксической роли членов предложения с двунаправленной связью, да и вопросы к ним не задает. Более естественным кажется  вопрос  к определению  (каким?). Но в то же время глагол управляет им как дополнением (кем?) – это вопрос для   Т.п.  Вот и получается такой «грамматический гибрид»  – скользкая тема, так что лучше, наверное, последовать ее примеру.